# pandas pivot dataframe to 3d data

Tags: python, pandas

There seem to be a lot of possibilities to pivot flat table data into a 3d array but I'm somehow not finding one that works: Suppose I have some data with columns=['name', 'type', 'date', 'value']. When I try to pivot via

```
pivot(index='name', columns=['type', 'date'], values='value')
```

I get

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Am I reading docs from dev pandas maybe? It seems like this is the usage described there. I am running 0.8 pandas.

I guess, I'm wondering if I have a MultiIndex ['x', 'y', 'z'] Series, is there a pandas way to put that in a panel? I can use groupby and get the job done, but then this is almost like what I would do in numpy to assemble an n-d array. Seems like a fairly generic operation so I would imagine it might be implemented already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pivot` only supports using a single column to generate your columns. You probably want to use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#pivot-tables) to generate a pivot table using multiple columns e.g.

```
pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table(your_dataframe, values='value', index='name', columns=['type', 'date'], aggfunc='sum')
```

The hierarchical columns that are mentioned in the [API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) and [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) for `pivot` relates to cases where you have multiple *value* fields rather than multiple *categories*.

Assuming 'type' and 'date' are categories, whose values should be used as the column names, then you should use `pivot_table`.

However, if you want separate columns for different value fields for the same category (e.g. 'type'), then you should use `pivot` without specifying the value column and your category as the columns parameter.

For example, suppose you have this DataFrame:

```
df = DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'type': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'date': ['2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', '2012-02-01'],  'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

pt = df.pivot_table(values='value', index='name', columns=['type', 'date'])
p = df.pivot('name', 'type')
```

pt will be:

```
type           1           2
date  2012-01-01  2012-02-01
name                        
A              1           3
B              2           4
```

and p will be:

```
          date              value   
type           1           2      1  2
name                                  
A     2012-01-01  2012-02-01      1  3
B     2012-01-01  2012-02-01      2  4
```

**NOTE**: For pandas version < 0.14.0, the `index` and `columns` keyword arguments should be replaced with `rows` and `cols` respectively.

Comment: This seems to be the case although the docs seem to imply pivoting to a panel is possible: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html Maybe this is an intention that has not yet been implemented?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to explain the differences, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the pandas philosophy is that you should probably work with your 3d data in a 2d multiindex array ... probably not a bad idea once you get used to indexing and slicing on multiindexes.

Comment: great answer, but now `rows` & `cols` are deprecated, please update the original answer to use `index` & `columns` instead. thanks

Comment: ... it is probably more intuitive/readable to stick to using stack/unstacks and groupby as in the other solution below. I basically never use pivot_table

Comment: Nowadays `p = df.pivot('name', 'type')` displays an error: `DataFrame.pivot() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`. Perhaps you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The original post ended with the question:

> "I'm wondering if I have a MultiIndex ['x', 'y', 'z'] Series, is there a pandas way to put that in a panel?"

to which I was looking for a solution myself.

I ended up with the following:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

## generate xyz example:
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({col:pd.np.random.randint(0,10,10) 
                               for col in ['x','y','z','data']})

## set all x,y,z coordinates as indices
In [5]: df.set_index(['x','y','z'], inplace=True)

## set the z coordinate as headers of the columns 
# NB: this is will turn the data into "dense" with NaNs where there were no 'data'
In [7]: df = df['data'].unstack()

## now it is ready to be "pivot"ed into a panel
In [9]: data_panel = df.to_panel()

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
     data                        
z       1   3   4   5   6   7   9
x y                              
1 5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
  6   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   0
2 9   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN
3 9     6 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5 9   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   8
7 1   NaN NaN NaN NaN   8 NaN NaN
  3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   5
  7   NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN
  9   NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9 5   NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN

[10 rows x 7 columns]

In [11]: data_panel
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 7 (items) x 6 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 1 to 9
Major_axis axis: 1 to 9
Minor_axis axis: 1 to 9
```

The columns headers will be the Items of the Panel, the first level index with be the MajorAxis (rows) and the second level will be the MinorAxis (columns)