# pandas: unexpected result when reindex(ing) a Panel

Tags: python, pandas, panel, reindex

This is a follow-up on my reply to [pandas pivot dataframe to 3d data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760160/1204331), where later I needed to re-index (get a different sorting of the Panel labels and of the elements accordingly, as well as filling in with NaNs of the missing labels).

reindex(ing) results in a "wrong" result when done on all axes of the Panel in one step.

Let me exemplify on artificial data:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df_dict = {'data': {0: 3.0,
   ...:                       1: 3.0,
   ...:                       2: 6.0,
   ...:                       3: 8.0,
   ...:                       4: 9.0,
   ...:                       5: 1.0,
   ...:                       6: 4.0,
   ...:                       7: 0.0,
   ...:                       8: 2.0,
   ...:                       9: 3.0},
   ...:                      'x': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 7, 8: 7, 9: 7},
   ...:                      'y': {0: 3, 1: 7, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 4, 5: 6, 6: 6, 7: 0, 8: 2, 9: 8},
   ...:                      'z': {0: 6, 1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 9, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 6, 7: 5, 8: 9, 9: 0}}

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

In [4]: df.set_index(['x','y','z'], inplace=True)

In [5]: df = df['data'].unstack() 

In [6]: data_panel = df.to_panel()
```

Now let's examine the result of reindex (including the filling of missing entries) on the 4th item, which originally did not have values at all:

```
In [7]: data_panel.reindex(items=range(11), minor_axis=range(11), major_axis=range(11))[4]
Out[7]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   8 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7  NaN NaN   2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

[11 rows x 11 columns]
```

When reindex is split in two steps, the expected result is retrieved:

```
In [8]: data_panel.reindex(items=range(11)).reindex(minor_axis=range(11), major_axis=range(11))[4]
Out[8]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

[11 rows x 11 columns]
```

Why do the two last lines result in different outputs?

## **Resolved** (thanx Jeff!):

This is a bug which was fixed in pandas 0.13.1
(though not in 0.13.0).

Updating resolves the issue.

See Jeff's comments bellow as well as the [github bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5905)

Comment: are you using 0.12 by any chance? their was a bug that is fixed in 0.13 that doesn't reindex properly when specifying all 3 axes, see : https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5905

Comment: @Jepd.__version__ reads '0.13.0'

Comment: sorry...meant bug was in 0.13.0....fixed in 0.13.1 (out now)

Comment: @Jeff So, this is indeed a bug and you already comitted a fix? If so than maybe this post could be closed. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug which was fixed in pandas 0.13.1
(though not in 0.13.0).

Updating resolves the issue.

See Jeff's comments to the question as well as the [github bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5905)